# Pronouncing the symbol $!$ as understood as a morphism in category theory.

Tags: category-theory, terminology, convention, pronunciation

> How does one pronounce the symbol $!$ as a morphism in category theory?

I heard it spoken as, "shriek" [here](https://youtu.be/ylxYw50nkPA), but I don't know whether that's the convention or not.

In my opinion, "exclamation mark" is a bit unwieldy. Besides, I have not heard it pronounced by anyone else that way other than by me.

I have also heard it pronounced, "shout" - although I don't know where from.

Please help :)

Comment: I have heard shriek and bang. I have occasionally heard "exclamation", but I agree it's unwieldy

Comment: I've only ever heard shriek I think...

Comment: In algebraic geometry I've heard shriek. Bang is more CS sounding to me.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard it pronounced--I would probably just say "the unique map".

Comment: As Eric points out, it depends from the context. If it's something like $A\overset{!}\to B$, then it's just "the unique map" (with an implicit "such that blah", where blah is something that has been discussed right before). If it's $f^{!}$ as in algebraic geometry, then it's pronounced shriek